# Problem with regex to remove double spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used simple JavaScript regex to remove double space:

Eg.

```
" I am                          working   on my Laptop.  "
as
"I am working on my laptop."
```

for that I used this function. but its nt working.

```
function valid(f)
{
    f.value = f.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s.'-,]/gixsm, '');
    f.value = f.value.replace(( /\s+/g, ' '); //remove more than 2 white spaces spaces.
    f.value = f.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); //remove spaces of before new line.
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear, pleases state your problem.

Comment: I need to remove double statement

>"I am           working   on my     Laptop."

>"I am working on my Laptop."
for that I wrote this regex, Its not workng.

Comment: is the double open paren a typo here or in the original code, too?

Comment: @jswolf: its not working for only spaces. Else for characters other than alpha.., space,dot,hyphen its going well.

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is the double `((` in this line:

```
f.value.replace(( /\s+/g, ' ');
```

After that, everything works.

```
var f = {};
f.value = " I am                          working   on my Laptop.  "

function valid(f)
{
    f.value = f.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s.'-,]/gixsm, '');
    // notice the single paren here!
    f.value = f.value.replace( /\s+/g, ' '); 
    f.value = f.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
}
valid(f)
console.log( f.value ) // I am working on my laptop.
```

Answer (score 0):

this works just fine

```
var string = " I am                          working   on my Laptop.  ";
function valid(f)
{
    f = f.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s.'-,]/gixsm, '');
    f = f.replace( /\s+/g, ' '); //remove more than 2 white spaces spaces.
    f = f.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); //remove spaces of before new line.
    return f;
}

document.write(valid(string));
```

you had an open parenthesis on the second replace.